# bvh human skeleton moves only around its hip (root) - and not in space. How to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, mediapipe

I have a bvh file constructed from data of 3d movement.
The bvh works well except of one (big) problem - the root is fixed and the movement is only around it.
For example - for a squat movement the legs are lifted towards the hips instead of the hips and rest of the body move downwards toward the feet/ground. Another example - the character walk is not moving in the space but only steps in the same space location.

The data is also built this way - the coordinates origin is the middle hip.

From what I've read the bvh file is always built in such way that the hip is the root, so i am not sure how to approach this issue.

Is it something that can be somehow fixed within blender/unity?

- I tried playing with the configuration within blender but couldn't find a good solution.

Is there a way to map the data with coordinates around the feet?
I would appreciate any ideas!

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.